# could not find database engine error handle 2016

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2016

I installed fresh windows on PC.
When installing 2016 made sure that startup account for sql server database engine is `nt authority/system`
Still get this error.
Please help. I am trying for two days on this.
Here is the error log.

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2061893607
  Start time:                    2016-08-25 11:52:45
  End time:                      2016-08-25 12:58:52
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for RS:              Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Next step for DQ:              Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Next step for Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  DESKTOP-5T4MDNN
  Machine processor count:       4
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.10240)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2016 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2016
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       13
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         D:\sql2016\en_sql_server_2016_developer_x64_dvd_8777069\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Developer

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Config
  ASDATADIR:                     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            DESKTOP-5T4MDNN\symon01107
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  NT Service\SSASTELEMETRY
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           Automatic
  ASTEMPDIR:                     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\DReplayClient\ResultDir\
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                Manual
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQL Server Distributed Replay Client
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\DReplayClient\WorkingDir\
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160825_115222\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               Manual
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                NT Service\SQL Server Distributed Replay Controller
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     DESKTOP-5T4MDNN\symon01107
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, FULLTEXT, DQ, AS, RS, RS_SHP, RS_SHPWFE, DQC, CONN, IS, BC, SDK, BOL, DREPLAY_CTLR, DREPLAY_CLT, SNAC_SDK, MDS
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MsDtsServer130
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  NT Service\SSISTELEMETRY130
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           Automatic
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           Automatic
  PBPORTRANGE:                   16450-16460
  PBSCALEOUT:                    false
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              SharePointFilesOnlyMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\ReportServer
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         true
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           DESKTOP-5T4MDNN\symon01107
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            4
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            true
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160825_115222\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Client Tools Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools SDK
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Reporting Services - Native
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A0019
  Error description:             Could not find the Database Engine startup handle.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1601.5&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A0019
  Error description:             Could not find the Database Engine startup handle.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1601.5&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025

  Feature:                       Data Quality Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A0019
  Error description:             Could not find the Database Engine startup handle.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1601.5&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025

  Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A0019
  Error description:             Could not find the Database Engine startup handle.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1601.5&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A0019
  Error description:             Could not find the Database Engine startup handle.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1601.5&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4025

  Feature:                       Master Data Services
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Distributed Replay Client
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Distributed Replay Controller
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Integration Services
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Data Quality Client
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Analysis Services
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Reporting Services - SharePoint
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Documentation Components
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Setup Support Files
  Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20160825_115222\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Comment: Could you please refer [could not find database engine startup handle](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24364.sql-server-troubleshooting-could-not-find-database-engine-startup-handle-error-during-installation.aspx). In this go to section *looking at SQL Server errorlog* now add the contents of errorlog in your question. This would tell us why the SQL Server is not coming online or failed.

Comment: Let me just make sure you checked correctly, I installed SQL Server 2016 on my PC on `E drive` and I have location `E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log`. So are you sure you looked at correct drives, if you have installed on other drive apart from C drive you need to check at that location.

Comment: Ok so go head and uninstall SQL Server from add remove programs and now when you start again make sure you select startup account for DB engine as NT Authority\System.

Comment: @Shanky when I try to uninstall it says Can uninstall because Supported products are alreay installed

Comment: @Shanky I tried again same error, nothing in the log. What should I do? I am lost here.

Comment: @Shanky What else I can try?